# How to overcome a ImportError?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, django-custom-user

In my project I want to realize a custom user model which is included in my users app and included to my settings, that has an entry for a project that is currently worked on. So my user model should look like this

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

from api.models import Project


class User(AbstractUser):
    current_project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
    )
```

While my Project model in the api app basically looks like

```
from django.db import models

from users.models import User


class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name="api_project_author",
        related_query_name="api_project_authors"
    )
    edited_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    editor = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name="api_project_editor",
        related_query_name="api_project_editors"
    )
```

However if I run this I get an *ImportError: cannot import name 'User' from 'users.models'* which obviously happens because of the reference in my User model which then tries to import the User model because of its other references.
So my idea was to create a new UserSetting model in the api app like

```
class UserSetting(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

However I am not sure how to handle such kind of problems properly or avoid them.

I am using Django 2.2 and Python 3.7.3

Comment: Have you specify `AUTH_USER_MODEL = app_name.User' for your custom user? You can to use `AUTH_USER_MODEL` instead `User`

Comment: And I would not advise to declare name of custom User model coincided with own django User model name

Comment: `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'` is what I meant when I wrote "included to my settings".

Comment: Ok. Try `from django.conf import settings` and `author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, ...)` - so the error remains?

Comment: Change User to 'users.User' in the model. This is called lazy relationship and comes handy in case of circular imports.

Comment: I got it now, thank you all. I also included lazy relationships, which I found to be more intuitive than importing models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when you're trying to use a custom user model in a relation, according to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#reusable-apps-and-auth-user-model) you should reference it via `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`. This should have been set if you followed the official guide on using custom user models [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

EDIT:

So your code would end up looking like:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    current_project = models.ForeignKey(
        'api.Project',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
    )
```

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models


class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name="api_project_author",
        related_query_name="api_project_authors"
    )
    edited_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    editor = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name="api_project_editor",
        related_query_name="api_project_editors"
    )
```

By referencing your user model that way, you're actually using the string that you set in your configs. Django will sort out references to the correct model for you.

Comment: This is what I meant when I wrote "included to my settings".

Comment: So in your `models.ForeignKey` declarations, you can replace the direct reference to the model. The thing about foreign keys and other relations in django is you can actually reference things by their app name. For instance I have the following declaration in one of my projects: `data = models.ForeignKey('data.Data', ...)`. Django will sort out the reference to the app and model for you.